# How does Nifi "Partition by Attribute" send FlowFiles to other Nifi nodes?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 3 node in nifi cluster. I'm using **"Partition by Attribute"** for distribute flow files to other nifi nodes in nifi cluster. For example, i am using **"type"** attribute for "Partition by Attribute";

```
FlowFile -> type: A
FlowFile -> type: B
FlowFile -> type: C
```

For this scenario, FlowFiles with the same "type" will go to the same node. But, suppose that one node(which the flow files with type A is sent) is down. While FlowFiles with "type B and C" will continue to be sent successfully, FlowFiles with "type A" will remain the queue(It will not be sent.).

Meanwhile, ***a FlowFile with "type XY" is coming(first-time. means it's never came before)***. In this case, is this incoming file only sent to nodes that actively receive data(nodes which FlowFiles with "type B and C" are sent)? Or, can it send it to the falling node?

For example for this problem;

```
FlowFile -> type: A -----> Waiting in the queue

FlowFile -> type: B ------> successfully sent

FlowFile -> type: C ------> successfully sent

and

FlowFile -> type: XY ------> Which node can be sent to? (B or C ?)
```

I dont want that flowfile with type XY go to unavailable cluster queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it calculates a node using all the nodes in the cluster (some of which may be unavailable), it doesn't really know whether the value was seen before, so the flow file with XY could still choose the unavailable node. The data would queue up and wait for the node to come back. If the node wasn't going to come back, then you could remove the node from the cluster, and then it would recalculate a new node for all of the queued flow files.